# Set ViewModel in UserControl.Resources from ancestor Page

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

Suppose I have a usercontrol as below.

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MyList"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Controls"
xmlns:viewModels="using:MyApp.ViewModels"
>
  <UserControl.Resources>
      <viewModels:CustomerViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <UserControl.DataContext>
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewModel}" />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <UserControl.Content>
      <ListView ItemsSource={Binding ItemList} />
  </UserControl.Content>
</UserControl>
```

I'm using this control in a Page:

```
<Page
  x:Class="MyApp.Views.CustomerPage"
  xmlns:control="using:MyApp.Controls">

    <controls:MyList />

</Page>
```

So far so good.

Now I'd like to re-use this same control for other ViewModels. My CustomerViewModel, like all my viewmodel is inherited from interface IViewModel.

What can I do to use the same control for let's say SalesOrderViewModel?

I tried the following, but that throws an XamlParseException exception upon InitializeComponent():

```
<Page
  x:Class="MyApp.Views.CustomerPage"
  xmlns:control="using:MyApp.Controls">

    <controls:MyList>
      <controls:MyList.Resources>
        <viewModels:SalesOrderViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
      </controls:MyList.Resources>
    </controls:>

</Page>
```

What would be a working approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewmodel (just my quickie, a bit different from yours):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = "Default";
}
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.MyList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the page, set different `DataContext`s for different `Usercontrol`s:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel1" Value="First"/>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel2" Value="Second"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <local:MyList DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel1}" />
    <local:MyList DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel2}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That's good Peter, thanks! I got this method working after rewriting the bindings in my control, to point to the datacontext instead of the staticresource which I now scrapped from my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data templates for this. You can set the data type of a data template with your view model.

```c#
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ImageViewModel}" >
    <view:ImageView/>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VideoViewModel}">
    <view:VideoView/>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

```c#
<UserControl x:Class="Overlay.View.ImageView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
       <Image Source="/Assets/screenshot.png"/>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="Overlay.View.VideoView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="Player" Source="./Assets/Sample_mp4.mp4"/>
</Grid>
```

Suppose you have a view model for your page control. This view model can have a property of type IViewModel which can be set depending on some conditions. You can bind this property to the content property of a content control or content presenter.

```c#
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ctnCtrl" Content="{Binding CurrentVm}"/>
```

The content control will load the view depending on your selected view model.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to create a different UserControl for each ViewModel type? 

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the same UserControl for different ViewModels each having an ItemList property.

(ps. listview in the usercontrol is for simplicity for this example, in reality the listview is a paged grid with rpc backend filtering)